# UITableView inside UITableViewCell using Interface Buillder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an tableView called BasicTable that have custom cell called CustomCell and I want to add a new table view inside this CustomCell.
I have an BasicTableView.m for BasicTable and CustomCell.m for CustomCell and add the new table view using Interface Builder but now don't know where to go or where to add reference to the new tableView and it's new cell.

Comment: What exactly is the question that you are asking? Please be specific in what your issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reference to the new tableView directly in `CustomCell.m` (e.g. by setting it as a property) and set the cell itself als `dataSource` and `delegate` of the `tableView`.

Having another tableView inside of a table view cell however doesn't seem like a good design decision, this will lead to problems in UX (e.g. concerning the scrolling of the two). Did you consider using sections inside the table view instead?

Also, if you use my above solution (which I wouldn't recommend because of the UX issues), be sure to update the tableView inside the table view cell, this should best be done in the table view cell's method `prepareForReuse`, it could look like this:

```
 - (void)prepareForReuse
 {
   [super prepareForReuse];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

And do this only after having updated the cell in  the table view controller in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I have to use this complex way because I have unknown numbers of label I want them to shown in every cell. Your solution is work with some UI issue but I'm working to solve them and make it better.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should connect your new tableview to your CustomCell and set it as datasource and delegate, and implement that protocols in you CustomCell.
i.e. your BasicTable controls by your ViewController, but new tableview controls by CustomCell.